# how to change connection string of crystall report that i already use wizard connection in crystal report designer with drag n drop field binding

Tags: mysql, vb.net, crystal-reports, odbc, vb.net-2010

anyone could help me to programatically change only connection string of crystal report. I already designed a report using basic drag n drop method from report desinger wizard with already bind with fields with the right panel tool that has already connected using ODBC wizard connecting wizard from there..

all i want is i can code that a connection string can be change but the fields binding are same. this scenario may use in my system that can easily be move to other computer and connect to database with the same database.. it's like dynamic connection string but still the drag n drop bindings still on connected with the new connection string.. same database..

I use MySQL Database , VB.NET 2010, Crystal Report for VB.Net 2010

Thank You..

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I can help you.
What I am doing is that I fill a datatable and apply it to the crystal Report.
My example is kind of different, since I upload the rpt file dynamically.

```
   Dim cryRpt As New ReportDocument
   Dim strReportPath As String = Me.selectedNode.RptLocation & "\" & Me.selectedNode.ReportFile 'The path for the rpt file
   cryRpt.Load(strReportPath)
   cryRpt.SetDataSource(crData) 'crData is the datatable that I am filling with data corresponding to the fields for the Crystal Report.
   crvReport.ReportSource = cryRpt  'crvReport is a CrystalReportViewer)
   crvReport.Zoom(2) ' use 1 for page width, or 2 for full page
```

I know that I am not helping you 100% but maybe you can find my answer as a little help.
Sorry I don't have time to recreate your problem and try to solve it.